# XCode hotkey jump to top and back

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Jump to the top is a simple matter, that is just <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd>. But the problem is, do XCode have a  hotkey to jump back to the previous area, AFTER the <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd>? (In the same file).

Comment: @SimonDugré, be careful, you have a lot of pending edits in the queue.  If too many people decide they're [not substantive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116660/170612), you may get banned from editing for 7 days. I don't know if that will happen, but you can monitor the status of your suggested edits [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/144701/simon-dugre?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Comment: Oups!! Well, thanks @GSee! I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @SimonDugré, Your edits seem to be well received by the community. Cheers!

Comment: @GSee, Perfect then! But I'll stop anyway... if for any reason I've get banned, it's not cool. So many time stack's save me from hours of search at my job... I dunno I could get banned from Stack so, now that I know it, I'll be more carefull. Thanks for the advice, I dunno there were having a rules on edition.

Comment: This is one shortcut I really want! I often go to the top but want to go immediately back to where I was before that, and for some reason Go Back doesn't work. I guess Xcode doesn't count it as a proper Jump.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut for Go Back. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> is for Go Forward.

Comment: That doesn't work if you go up with cmd + up. Already tried that :)

Answer (score 2):

Before pressing CMD + UP remember the current line number and then using CMD + L you can go back to the old line number.